# Could I recompile php after install with apt-get?

Tags: apache2, php

the title says a lot I guess, I want to install my lamp serve with:

```
apt-get install lamp-server^
```

And after that I want to recompile the php to add the pthreads,

it is possible install the lamp server without install all server from the source?

Answer (score 1):

Install the various utilities needed

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev apache2 build-essential
```

Then compile PHP as-per instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php with any modifications you desire.

I'd recommend keeping the source in /usr/src so that you can recompile and relink apache anytime you apt-get update apache, (as you may have to recompile your version of PHP to ensure the versions match up).  Also make a little "install.sh" script or README there with your configure parameters for future use.

Bonus points if you want both the distro version and source version of PHP available and installed, use the --prefix=/usr/local/php5x flag on configure to install to a different directory than the system default.